# How to convert []interface{} to custom defined type - Go lang?

Tags: go

I am started working in `Go`. Having the following code

```
 type Transaction struct{
      Id string `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
      TransId string 
 }

 func GetTransactionID() (id interface{}, err error){
  query := bson.M{}
  transId, err := dbEngine.Find("transactionId", WalletDB, query)
  //transId is []interface{} type
  id, err1 := transId.(Transaction)
  return transId, err
}
```

#### Find

```
package dbEngine 
func Find(collectionName,dbName string, query interface{})(result []interface{}, err error){
   collection := session.DB(dbName).C(collectionName)
   err = collection.Find(query).All(&result)
   return result, err
}
```

#### Problem

`Error:` invalid type assertion: transId.(string) (non-interface type []interface {} on left)

Any suggestion to change the `[]interface{}` to `Transaction` type.

Comment: show us the `.Find` function.

Answer (score 8):

You can't convert a slice of `interface{}`s into any single struct. Are you sure you don't really want a slice of `Transaction`s (i.e. a `[]Transaction` type)? If so, you'll have to loop over it and convert each one:

```
for _, id := range transId {
    id.(Transaction) // do something with this
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I m new to go lang. I m trying to print the value it is not working. for _, id := range transId {
     value := id.(Transaction)
     fmt.Println("Db values", value)
 }  Anything wrong in my approach.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Can you put a working snippet on the playground (http://play.golang.org/) so I can see the exact error etc?